# "from different teams" or "on different teams"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions

I'd like to explain a story where two students who are not on the same sport team became good friends.

Can I say

> "a friendship between students who are **from** different sport teams"

or

> "a friendship between students who are **on** different sport teams"

?

this phrase is said when a hero of a story shortly explains his friend the content of a play where he will take part in.

He says "Its story is about a friendship between student athletes on/from different teams."

In my story the content of the play doesn't matter.

Comment: Both choices look good. It's not natural to say "sports teams". It feels redundant and clunky. Consider, "*a friendship between **student athletes** on different teams*"

Comment: @gotube Thank you so much! It's a great help.

Comment: Word choice depends on the surrounding sentences. What is the whole paragraph?  Your example sentence might be reworded depending on what precedes it and what follows it. In this limited context, either "on" or "from" is acceptable.

Comment: @Sam Thank you very much for the information!  I added more information about my sentences.  It's about a play, so does it depend on the content of the play?

Comment: @Nigutumok  Add the word "who".  Choice 1: "... who are from teams."  Choice 2: "who happen to be from different teams". etc.  I slightly prefer "from" here, but it's still open to interpretation.

Comment: @Sam Oh, I see.  How difficult it is to write natural English! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. "A friendship between students **on** different teams" and "a friendship between students **from** different teams" are both valid.

- I would say **on** is more neutral; it simply says that the students are part of different teams.
- **From** perhaps takes the perspective of somebody who is trying to pick out individuals from existing groups (the teams) to mentally move them into a different group (i.e. the group of friends). Thus, the teams are construed as the *source* of individuals for the friend group (though in reality the students belong to both groups simultaneously).

Similarly, in politics, you can say "people **on/from** both sides agree that..." or "people **in/from** both parties agree that...".